# UIContextualAction with destructive style seems to delete row by default

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe, ios11

The problem I'm seeing is that when I create a `UIContextualAction` with `.destructive` **and** pass `true` in `completionHandler` there seems to be a default action for removing the row.

If you create a new Master-Detail App from Xcode's templates and add this code in `MasterViewController`...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let testAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Test") { (_, _, completionHandler) in
        print("test")
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [testAction])
}
```

the row you swipe will be removed. Notice that there's no code there updating the table view. Also the model is not updated and if you scroll way up to cause the row to be reloaded it will reappear.

Passing `false` in this case does not remove the row. Or using the `.normal` style and `true` also does not remove the row.

`.destructive` and `true` results in the row being removed by default.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Why is the row being removed?

Answer (score 18):

Per the documentation for the Destructive option:

> An action that deletes data or performs some type of destructive task.

The completion is meant to signify if the action was a success.  Passing true would mean that the destructive task was a success and thus the row should be removed.

You are meant to manually update your dataSource when the destructive action occurs and not doing so would cause scrolling to make the data reappear.  You will also need to tell the tableView that the data has been deleted.

Below is some code showing a working example:

```
UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [weak self] (_, _, completion) in
    if self?.canDelete(indexPath) { // We can actually delete
        // remove the object from the data source
        self?.myData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // delete the row.  Without deleting the row or reloading the
        // tableview, the index will be off in future swipes
        self?.tableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        // Let the action know it was a success.  In this case the 
        // tableview will animate the cell removal with the swipe
        completion(true)    
    } else { // We can't delete for some reason
        // This resets the swipe state and nothing is removed from
        // the screen visually.
        completion(false)
    }         
}
```

Then I need to reload the `tableview` or call `deleteRows` in order to have the `indexPath` be properly computed on the next swipe.

If I have 10 rows and I swipe the 5th one to delete, every one after that will be off by one row unless the `tableview` is reloaded or the `tableview` is told of the row being removed in some way.

Comment: Following this code I get a crash. The reason is -- you shouldn't be deleting the row by yourself  in this line *self?.tableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)*. The UIKit does the deleting row when you call *completion(true)*

Answer (score 5):

I can't reproduce this issue in iOS 13. Either the behavior in iOS 12 and before was a bug or it has simply been withdrawn (perhaps because it was confusing).

In iOS 13, if you just return from a `.destructive` action by calling `completion(true)` without doing anything, nothing happens and that's the end of the matter. The cell is *not* deleted for you.

Comment: Its true that the behaviour is different for iOS12 and iOS13, and I thought this is a bug, https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/1923

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer by [Kris Gellci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898748/668253), but notice that if you are using a **NSFetchedResultsController** it may complicate things. It seems that for a destructive UIContextualAction the call `completion(true)` will delete the row, but so may the NSFetchedResultsController's delegate. So you can easily end up with errors in that way. With NSFetchedResultsController I decided to call `completion(false)` (to make the contextual menu close), regardless of whether the action was a success or not, and then let the delegate take care of deleting the table row if the corresponding object has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below flag for disabling full swipe.

> performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe

By default it will automatically performs the first action which is configured in UISwipeActionsConfiguration. so if you want to disable full swipe delete then set "performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe" as false.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let test = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "test") { (action, view, completion) in
        
        // Your Logic here
        completion(true)
    }
    
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [test])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.